# Real-world example of a preorder relation which is not a partial order

Tags: order-theory

I have tried long and hard to find a real-world occurrence of a preorder relation which is not a partial order, but couldn't find any.

Can someone give a *real-world example* of a such a relation, that is, a relation which is reflexive and transitive but not antisymmetric?

By *"real-world"* I don't mean that it cannot be abstract; but it shouldn't be contrived. Examples from mathematics / physics / computer science / etc. are all elligible, as long as they occur naturally.

Comment: How about the preorder on people: $A\le B$ iff $A$ is not taller than $B$.

Comment: A mathematical example of a naturally occuring preorder is the specialization preorder on a topological space

Comment: The relation $a$ divides $b$ where $a,b$ are integers. The relation $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ where $f(x),g(x)$ are polynomials. The relation "$A$ is isomorphic to a subset of $B$" where $A,B$ are totally ordered sets. The relation "$X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $Y$" where $X,Y$ are topological spaces. The relation "there is an injective map $f:A\to B$" where $A,B$ are sets. The relation "$\alpha$ is a logical consequence of $\beta$" where $\alpha,\beta$ are first order sentences.These examples **all** seem contrived to you? Or you didn't come across any of them in your long & hard search?

Comment: If you want top. spaces or any other category: $A\le B$ iff there is a morphism $B\to A$.

Comment: $f(x)=o(g(x))$, $f(x)=O(g(x))$. Actually, "preorders" (quasi-orders) come up much more naturally than partial orders. In the real world, the usual way you get a partial order relation is by starting with a natural preorder relation and then passing to equivalence classes.

Comment: @Yes, I've already deleted my comment.